# Como implementar una confirmacion antes de ejecutar un UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, mysqli, modal

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    //APROBAR PAGOS MENSUALIDAD
 function aprobar_pago_mes() {
     global $db;
    $idusuario = ($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "UPDATE pagos SET
            status_pago = 'APROBADO'
            WHERE id = '$idusuario'";

if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    $_SESSION['pago_mensualidad']  = "Se ha Actualizado el usuario de manera correcta..!!";

 } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
    mysqli_close($db);
 } }
```

Asi como esta el funciona perfectamente, pero quisiera saber si es posible implementar en ese codigo un modal o un boton de confirmación antes de ejecutar el UPDATE.
Estoy usando Bootstrap 4.

En el PHP donde esta el boton `EDITAR` he intentado con lo siguiente:

```
      echo '<script language="javascript">
      function msg(){
        actualizar=confirm("¿Seguro que Desea Aprobar este pago?");
        if (actualizar)
   //Redireccionamos si das a aceptar
     window.location.href="mensualidades.php?id=';
     echo $rowid;
     echo '&user=';
     echo $rowUser;
     echo '"//página web a la que te redirecciona si confirmas la eliminación
else
  //Y aquí pon cualquier cosa que quieras que salga si le diste al boton de cancelar
    alert("No se Aprobo este pago")
      }
      </script>';
      $link_aprobar_mes = '<form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "mensualidades.php?id='.$rowid.'&user='.$rowUser.'"><button onclick="msg()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="aprobar_pago_btn">Aprobar</button> </form>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$rowid.'</td>
       <td>'.$rowUser.'</td>
       <td>'.$fecha_pago .'</td>
       <td>'.$rowmes['monto'].' BsS / '.$rowmes['mes_de_pago']. '</td>
       <td>'.$rowmes['nro_transf'] . ' / '.$rowmes['ci_nro_cuenta'].'</td>
       <td>'.$rowmes['banco_origen'].' / '.$rowmes['banco_destino'] .'</td>
       <td>'.$link_aprobar_mes .'</td>
      </tr>';
```

Pero asi el usuario cancele la accion del `confirm()` el script php se ejecuta de igual manera y realiza el Update y envia correo etc etc..!

Comment: Realmente esos famosos *Dialog box*  que antes parecían tan bonitos hoy día van cayendo en desuso. Si lo piensas bien: ¿para qué sirven en este contexto? Si en tu página tienes un botón `Actualizar` y se presiona sobre él es porque se quiere actualizar... ¿qué sentido tiene **preguntar de nuevo** algo como *`¿Estás seguro de que quieres actualizar? Yes / No`*  Eso era en el siglo pasado, cuando Windows empezó a tratar al usuario como si fuera un idiota. Si él presionó un botón es porque quiere que la acción de ese botón se realice, es lógico.

Comment: Saludos @A.Cedano El boton esta en un listado donde hay muchos datos y puede ocurrir que de manera equivocada alguno de los admin le de click al boton equivocado, es decir al boton editar de otro usuario el que este por debajo o por arriba al usuario en cuestion..! de momento tal cual como lo tengo la table la tengo con la opcion hover activada para que visualmente el hover mantenga iluminado la fila del usuario que se le desea aplicar dicha opcion. Pero en las laptos el uso de los touchpad pueden hacer que una persona pueda cometer un error.

Comment: Entiendo José. No te digo que no lo hagas así. Sin embargo con mi comentario quiero abrir otro horizonte. Si tienes la libertad de mejorar el diseño, ¡hazlo!, los botones no tienen por qué estar uno encima del otro. Hoy día existen lo que se llaman diseños *responsive*, que según el tamaño/tipo de dispositivo el contenido se adapta a la pantalla. En informática hay algo que se llama *experiencia de usuario*, que invita a crear programas agradables de usar. No tienes por qué conformarte con un **molesto** dialog box de confirmación que empobrece la experiencia de usuario, mejora el diseño.

Comment: He editado mi consulta y he agregado el codigo PHP donde esta el boton EDITAR

Comment: Si claro @A.Cedano comprendo tu orientacion y muy humildemente te digo que me parece genial, por mi parte te comento que el diseño que tengo es responsive me estoy apoyando en Bootstrap pero por otra parte estoy tratando de cuidar errores del tipo que comente antes..!

Comment: De acuerdo. En ese caso, lo mejor sería implementar un código Javascript en el cliente. Al presionar el botón `Actualizar` lanzarías un diálogo desde Javascript y en función de la respuesta lanzas una petición Ajax que gestiona la actualización en el servidor si el usuario confirma que quiere realmente actualizar.

Comment: yo lo que haria es cambiar el boton. Y en lugar de llamarle "Actualizar" lo llamaria "Confirmar". y cuando el usuario pulse "confirmar" lanzas un emergente que contiene el boton "ACTUALIZAR".